# Kiosk mode iOS app and auto update from appstore

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I'm developing app which is going to be constantly running in foreground on iPad devices in Kiosk mode. Does auto update work in this case (assuming auto update app is enabled in device settings)?

In my opinion NO and I have to manually check i.e once a day and if new version appear in the AppStore. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right.
iOS doesn’t allow any updates in Kiosk mode. So, as an admin, if one needs to update the app, you would remove the app lock policy, then push the app update, and then re-apply the app lock policy.

[Refer this](https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/359506-update-app-with-kiosk-mode-enable/)